# Client-Side Validation breaking @Html.DisplayFor and Content Hide/Show

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a find officer control that postbacks to get the officer information from AD. When the information is returned i unhide the div that contains the informaiton.  Everything works until i submit the form and it goes through Client Side validation. I am getting the following problems.

- When the i submit the form for client-side validation the `@html.DisplayFor` helper methods do not contain any information.  The `@Html.HiddenFor` does contain all the correct information.
- Also, at the same time my Hide and Show no longer works.

Is there a way to get `@html.DisplayFor` working? Having a Read-only text box will not suffice as I am after just the plain text.

Is there a better way for the Hide / Show.  The code i have is pretty shocking and i am sure there is a better way of doing it that works on both Postback and Client Side validation?

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span3">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RequestingPayroll)
        </div>
        <div class="span4">
            <div class="input-append">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.RequestingPayroll, new { @class = "span6", placeholder = "payroll" })
                <button type="submit" id="btnSubmit" name="Command" value="FindOfficer" class="btn cancel">Find Officer</button>
            </div>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RequestingPayroll) 

        </div><!--/span-->
    </div>
    @if (Model != null)
    {
        if (Model.RequestingFirstName != "" && Model.RequestingFirstName != null)
        {
            ViewBag.RequestingPayroll = "";
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.RequestingPayroll = "hide";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ViewBag.RequestingPayroll = "hide";
    }

    <div id="requesting-payroll" class="row-fluid row-form @ViewBag.RequestingPayroll">
        <div class="offset3 span9">
            <div class="alert alert-info">
                <strong><span class="capitalise">@Html.DisplayTextFor(model => model.RequestingLastName)</span>, @Html.DisplayTextFor(model => model.RequestingFirstName) (@Html.DisplayTextFor(model => model.RequestingRank))</strong><br />
                @Html.DisplayTextFor(model => model.RequestingStationUnit) <br />
                <strong>phone:</strong> @Html.DisplayTextFor(model => model.RequestingPhone), <strong>mobile:</strong> @Html.DisplayTextFor(model => model.RequestingMobile) 

                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.RequestingLastName)
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.RequestingFirstName)
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.RequestingRank)
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.RequestingStationUnit)
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.RequestingPhone)
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.RequestingMobile) 

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is my controller code

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(DPACS.Models.Request request, string Command)
    {
        if (Command == "FindOfficer")
        {
            QpsUser user = CommonMethods.FindQpsUser(request.RequestingPayroll.ToString());
            if (user != null)
            {
                ModelState.Clear();
                request.RequestingRank = user.Rank;
                request.RequestingFirstName = user.FirstName;
                request.RequestingLastName = user.LastName;
                request.RequestingPhone = user.PhoneNumber;
                request.RequestingMobile = user.MobileNumber;
                request.RequestingStationUnit = user.Station;

                return View(request);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: it sounds to me like on your controller you aren't passing the full model back to the view when you do validation.  Make sure you are populating and sending back the model.

Comment: The data appears to be getting passed back.  Everything gets displayed correctly up until the form is submitted for client side validation.  I have supressed validation on the find officer control.  I have modified my post to include the controller code

Comment: if you put a breakpoint on the controller is the request object populated before it comes back to the view?

Comment: Yeah.  I tested the model and everything is being set correctly when passed back to the view